# How to determine that remaining of dividing number X by number Y is zero using regular expression

Tags: asp.net, regex, validation

i want to know is it possible to validate that deviding two number has remaining zero in result or not?

for example dividing  number 4 on number two has zero in remaining.
4/2=0 (this is true)
but 4/3=1 (this is not true)

is there any expression for validation such case?

Better Question :
**Is There any validation expression to validate this sentence ?**

> Remainder is zero

thank you

Comment: Regular expressions aren't magic. They're for matching patterns. Computing a remainder is not pattern matching. Why do you think you have to solve it using a regular expression? ASP.NET has many ways of validating input.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a Modulo operator. The modulo operation finds the remainder of division of one number by another

```
y mod x
5 mod 2 =1 (2x2=4, 5-4=1)
9 mod 3 = 0 (3*3=9)
```

You can think of it, how many times does x fit in y and then take the remainder.

In computing the modulo operator is integrated in most programming languages, along with division, substraction etc. Check modulo and then your language on google (probably its mod).

Answer (score 0):

This is called the modulo function. It essentially gives the remainder of a division of two integer number. So you can test for the modulo funtion returning zero. For example, in Python you would write

```
if a % b == 0:
  # a can be divided by b with zero remainder
```